# Moving the cursor inside of QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit, qtextcursor

I have a form with a `QTextEdit` on it, which is called `translationInput`. I am trying to provide the editing functionality for the user.

This `QTextEdit` will contain HTML-formatted text. I have a set of buttons, like "**bold**", "*Italic*", and so on, which should add the corresponding tags into the document. If the button is pressed when no text is selected, I just want to insert a pair of tags, for example, `<b></b>`. If some text is selected, I want the tags to appear left and right from it.

This works fine. However, I also want the cursor to be placed *before the closing tag* after that, so the user will be able to continue typing inside the new-added tag without needing to reposition the cursor manually. By default, the cursor appears right *after* the new-added text (so in my case, right after the closing tag).

Here's the code that I have for the *Italic* button:

```
//getting the selected text(if any), and adding tags.
QString newText = ui.translationInput->textCursor().selectedText().prepend("<i>").append("</i>");
//Inserting the new-formed text into the edit
ui.translationInput->insertPlainText( newText );
//Returning focus to the edit
ui.translationInput->setFocus();
//!!! Here I want to move the cursor 4 characters left to place it before the </i> tag.
ui.translationInput->textCursor().movePosition(QTextCursor::Left, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor, 4);
```

However, the last line doesn't do anything, the cursor doesn't move, even though the `movePosition()` returns `true`, which means that all of the operations were successfully completed.

I've also tried doing this with `QTextCursor::PreviousCharacter` instead of `QTextCursor::Left`, and tried moving it before and after returning the focus to the edit, that changes nothing.

So the question is, how do I move the cursor inside my `QTextEdit`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Solved the issue by digging deeper into the docs.

The `textCursor()` function returns a *copy* of the cursor from the `QTextEdit`. So, to modify the actual one, `setTextCursor()` function must be used:

```
QTextCursor tmpCursor = ui.translationInput->textCursor();
tmpCursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Left, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor, 4);
ui.translationInput->setTextCursor(tmpCursor);
```

Comment: You can directly move the text cursor by using `moveCursor()`:
`ui.translationInput->moveCursor(QTextCursor::Left, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor, 4);`

Comment: I think the above comment should be turned into an answer.

Comment: The `moveCursor()` example in above comment is wrong. This function only takes 2 arguments: `void QTextEdit::moveCursor(QTextCursor::MoveOperation operation, QTextCursor::MoveMode mode = QTextCursor::MoveAnchor)`

Answer (score 0):

In PyQt (move cursor to the end of the document):

```
txt = QTextEdit()
txt.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End, QTextCursor.MoveAnchor)
```